# ID token and access token handling

Tags: .net, security, oauth, openid-connect

I read a little bit about OAuth and OIDC protocols. And there is this concept I find a bit hard to understand: ID token is meant to be read by the application client while the access token is meant to be read by the API.

But it doesn't stop there, I also read stuff like ID token is for the front-end and the access for the back-end.

For me it's confusing, e.g: I created a web app using .net, front and backend. When I'm logging in, **the client has both, ID and access tokens**.

> Also, access token is sent to the server that client/front does not see in order to prevent hackers to steal the token.

It seems obvious for some but I can't understand it very well since both tokens go through the client first. (I'm just talking about the pure fundamentals, not the split token or phantom token or anything like that)

Can someone enlighten me on this matter please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID token main purpose is to allow the client to create the user cookie-based session. AFter that, the ID-token has no purpose; the token typically has a very short lifetime, like 5 minutes in some setups. The ID-token typically describes who is authenticated and claims/facts about the user. In theory the client can discard the ID-token after it has created the local session.

The client, typically also receives an access token that it can use to access backend API's. The client can also ask for a refresh token to automate the renewal of the access token when it expires.

Comment: Thank you for the details. It has helped me to clarify a few things on it. So, if I can rephrase it: the fact id token is stored in the form of cookies in the browser, is that what people mean with "id token can be seen via the browser unlike access token?"

Comment: Not really. Don't need to store the ID-token in any cookie, the local session is created bsaed on this ID-token and after that you typically have no use for it. It typically has a very short lifetime, like 5 minutes in some systems. 

The ID-token should in a modern implementation never bee seen by the browser, but in some older flows (implicit flow) the token was passed via the browser back to the client.

Comment: OK ok. I think i was confusing front-end + backend and client and browser. Whether it's an SPA or not, the id token should just not be passed via the browser. Which is the biggest flaw of implicit flow. But ... what does exactly mean "via the browser", because, if the id token is visible in a request, whether as a query parameter, or header parameter, I consider this as "via the browser", however in this case, i don't understand how the client would get the token anyway without being exposed?

Comment: Modern applications should not use the implicit flow, instead you should use the authorization code flow, with this flow, the tokens never touches the browser.. The tokens are retrieved by the backend client using a direct request to the token service.

Comment: Also, when dealing with OpenID-connect, I highly recommend putting the SPA/Client, Token Service, and the API in separate services. Otherwise, it will be hard to reason about the system when you combine them. For modern SPA applications, I would consider using the BFF pattern (Google)

Comment: Let me know if you have any more questions

Comment: Looking back, I realized I haven't said thanks. Also, my issue with the spa was that I did not understand that even if we inject the code into the browser, there is still a backend (nodeJs) behind all of it. And that is what you meant, I hope, by the backend client retrieving the token in the code flow (and not a bff to be implemented which retrieves the token)

Comment: The BFF is a complement to the client that uses Code flow, so that you don't need to send any tokens down to the browser. But the BFF is not a requirement. Feel free to accept my answer if it helped you.